# Bug bootstrap com Angular

Tags: html5, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com este problema no meu projeto, adicionei o bootstrap 4.3.1 normalmente no projeto com angular, porém ao tentar dividir as colunas como o código abaixo essa margem aparece impossibilitando que a divisão de grid do bootstrap aconteça, e não adicionei mais nenhum outro CSS.

```
<div clas="row">
    <div class="col-7">
        Coluna 1
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        Coluna 2
    </div>
</div>
```

E esse código acima aparece na rota deste código

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara vc escreve a `class` da `row` errado, vc colocou `clas` ai sem a `row` a `col` não funciona

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que arrumando isso volta a funcionar perfeitamente

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
            Coluna 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            Coluna 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```